# Design Approach for Custom Control in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, custom-controls

Am Creating a user control which will have a button, textbox and label. And i have created some delegates for Button and Textbox.

1. Now, i need some properties like assign text, visibility and some
   other at runtime. For this whether shall i creating a Button itself
   as property (or) creating each property for text and visibility. Which one is a good approach ?
2. I have created some custom events for Button. Now i have to avoid
   the default events which is like OnClick e.t.c. Is it possible ?

Comment: UserControls strongly favor *encapsulation*.  Keep these controls as private members of your class.  Expose your own events and properties.  An event like Click doesn't make much sense, you'd expose something like Submit or Change.

Comment: But usually for a button there will be many properties how to expose all of those ?